# Interface (IOwnerRepository) is not resolved while attempting to activate controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-core

I have an Interface as below: This interface is my GetAllOwners method signature.

```
namespace Pms.Core
{
   public interface IOwnerRepository
   {
       Task<IEnumerable<Owner>> GetAllOwners();        
   }
}
```

My Repository class that drives this interface is like below. This class should return all the owners in the database.

```
namespace Pms.Persistence
{
    public class OwnerRepository : IOwnerRepository
    {
        private readonly PmsDbContext context;
        public OwnerRepository(PmsDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Owner>> GetAllOwners()
        {
            return await context.Owners.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a controller class that uses Repository class to display all the owners.

```
namespace Pms.Controllers
{
    [Route("/api/owners")]
    public class OwnersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PmsDbContext context;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        private readonly IOwnerRepository repository;

        public OwnersController(PmsDbContext context, IMapper mapper, 
IOwnerRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.context = context;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<OwnerResource>> GetOwners()
        {
            var owners = await repository.GetAllOwners();
            return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Owner>, 
               IEnumerable<OwnerResource>>(owners);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is my code snippet that I register my services.

```
services.AddScoped<IOwnerRepository, OwnerRepository>();
```

When I test this API, I get "*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Pms.Core.IOwnerRepository' while attempting to activate 'Pms.Controllers.OwnersController'.*"

What I have done is to make sure that the API works without the interface. This application works just fine without using interface but somehow I can't implement the interface to make my application more robust and object oriented.

Comment: Where are you registering your service?

Comment: Startup.cs is the class that I register my services. Here is the code that I use: **services.AddScoped<IOwnerRepository, OwnerRepository>();**

Comment: Please add code to the question itself, not as a comment.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well nothing stands out to me.  Everything in your question looks correct.

Comment: Well, I found the solution which I also posted below. Interesting.

Comment: Weird how stuff works out like that sometimes.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the guilty offender. The version of the Dependency Injection is not compatible. I was using 2.0 so I downgraded to 1.2.0 and everything works.

```
<PackageReference
      Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="1.2.0" />
```